# Gitlab returning remote: You do not have permissions to do this. while performing scripted git push

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, ssh-keys, mirror

My scenario is as follows:

we have a gitlab set up for our team where we do all of our development with branches etc, etc. We also have an official repo hosted by our company where we would like to have our master branch mirrored so that people (that have access to this repo in our company) can view our code.

I have written a `post-receive` hook that would mirror commits pushed to master branch on gitlab towards the official repo: (`/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/post-receive` on gitlab)

```
#!/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
# Fix the PATH so that gitlab-shell can find git-upload-pack and friends.
ENV['PATH'] = '/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:' + ENV['PATH']

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file was placed here by GitLab. It makes sure that your pushed commits
# will be processed properly.
#
deveo_server="deveo@deveo.XXXX.com:XXXX/projects/XXXX/repositories/git/Project"

from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "
if (branch =~ /master$/) == nil
    puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end

`git remote add deveo #{deveo_server} >/dev/null 2>&1`
`git push deveo master`
 puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) mirrored to '#{deveo_server}'"

refs = ARGF.read
key_id  = ENV['GL_ID']
repo_path = Dir.pwd

require_relative '../lib/gitlab_custom_hook'
require_relative '../lib/gitlab_post_receive'

if GitlabPostReceive.new(repo_path, key_id, refs).exec &&
    GitlabCustomHook.new.post_receive(refs, repo_path)
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
end
```

The problem is that when I do this I receive the following on commits to gitlab's master branch:

```
[master aa4a4f2] testing hooks 7
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 testing_hooks_7
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 264 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: You do not have permissions to do this.
remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote: 
remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote: and the repository exists.
remote: DEPLOY: master(aa4a4f218b7bc335ee3e0d6d52df5cfd5ddc1c99) mirrored to 'deveo@deveo.XXXX.com:XXXX/projects/XXXX/repositories/git/Project'
To git@projectgitlab.net:XXXX/Project.git
   1e92695..aa4a4f2  master -> master
```

I have launched ssh agent there and added `git` user's ssh from gitlab to deveo but something is missing.

This has worked when I set up this with bare repo next to my local repository on my local machine - so there has to be some keys missing somewhere.. but where :( ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that the bot (in deveo) that I have created was a `read-only` bot. I needed to go to in deveo to `project options`->`Settings and bot accounts`->`bot`->`give this bot write permissions to repositories`.

And of course I needed to add `git` user ssh key (from gitlab's host) to deveo.

Now it works fine :)